# Detect template class member function that takes strong enum argument , using Detection Idiom

Tags: c++, object-detection, type-traits

I use the code below namespace W_ASL_is_detected_exact to detect, type traits.
Its supposed to do the same thing as std::experimental::is_detected, but i use this code cause std::experimental not available in Visual Studio MSVC.

Works perfectly, for all including template functions.
But cant get it to detect template function that uses enum template argument

```
namespace W_ASL_is_detected_exact
        {
            template< class... >
            using void_t = void;

            struct nonesuch {
                nonesuch() = delete;
                ~nonesuch() = delete;
                nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
                void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
            };

            namespace detail {
                template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid,
                    template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                struct detector {
                    using value_t = std::false_type;
                    using type = Default;
                };

                template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
                struct detector<Default, void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
                    using value_t = std::true_type;
                    using type = Op<Args...>;
                };

            } // namespace detail

            template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
            using is_detected = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;

            template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
            using detected_t = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::type;

            template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
            using detected_or = detail::detector<Default, void, Op, Args...>;
        }//W_ASL_is_detected_exact

        template <class Expected, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
        using ASL_is_detected_exact = std::is_same<Expected, W_ASL_is_detected_exact::detected_t<Op, Args...>>;
```

Works very well to detect functions in a given type T.

Here is Test Class that contains functions i want to detect

```
enum class E_ClsState :unsigned int
            {
                e1,e2,e3
            };

     class CTestClass
    {
         template<int iVal>
         void TestFunc_Int()
         {

         }

         template<E_ClsState clsSate>
         void TestFunc_Enum()
         {

         }


    }
```

Here is the trait checking template class that does the detection

```
  template<class T_IStateParent>
    class SPT_IStateParent_T :
    {
        //describe trait for TestFunc_int
        template<class t_IStateParent>
        using t_has_TestFunc_int = decltype(
            std::declval<t_IStateParent&>().template TestFunc_int< 1 >()
                        );
        //create function to test for TestFunc_int
        static constexpr bool Check_TestFunc_int()
        {
            return ASL_is_detected_exact<
            void,
            t_has_TestFunc_int,
            T_IStateParent
            >{};

        }

    //describe trait for TestFunc_enum
    template<class t_IStateParent>
        using t_has_TestFunc_enum = decltype(
        std::declval<t_IStateParent&>().template TestFunc_enum<E_ClsState::e1>()
                        );

         //create function to test for TestFunc_enum
        static constexpr bool Check_TestFunc_enum()
        {
            return ASL_is_detected_exact<
            void,
            t_has_TestFunc_enum,
            T_IStateParent
            >{};

        }

        //This is equivalent of main for this test
        //consume type traits here using static_assert 
        SPT_IStateParent_T ()
       {  
           //T_IStateParent here is class CTestClass 

          static_assert(Check_TestFunc_int())//this works
           static_assert(Check_TestFunc_enum())//this fails
       }


    }
```

Problem is i need help to know how to use this API to detect Template member function whose parameter is strongly typed enum.

Currently it works for all functions including template function, but fails when template function argument is enum.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: "i need help to know how to use this API to detect Template member function" - Please, can you explain better this point? Can you add an use example?

Comment: Thats why i added  working example based on non template member function. The type check is consumed in SPT_IStateParent_T() to complete the example.

Comment: not sure to understand... please, correct me if I'm wrong: do you want to modify `SPT_IStateParent_T` -- that works to check if a class has a `imp_ifo_GetObjectState()` method, receiving no arguments -- to check a `imp_ifo_GetObjectState()` template method. If this is correct: do you want to pass to `SPT_IStateParent_T` some types; the template types for the method? And the template method can deduce all template types from arguments or there are types that must be explicated?

Comment: You are pretty much correct. Detect that type T has  E_ObjState imp_ifo_GetObjectState() { }. SPT_IStateParent_T<T> is the class that does the check. type T argument of SPT_IStateParent_T is the class thats being checked. The trait check is being done in constructor of SPT_IStateParent_T inside the static_assert. Thank you very much for asking.

Comment: Please see this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected    to better understand the API i am using cause its the same thing. And the question is how to use detection idiom to detect class member template function. I already use it to detect non template member functions no problem.

Comment: Hi this actually works as youd expect for template function. Problem am now having is that detection of template function that takes enum argument is not working. It detects template function with example int value argument, but not enum

Comment: Suggestion: modify your question with a minimal, but **complete** example, of your working with template method code. And add the part of your not working with enum template method code. Otherwise is very very difficult understand your exact problem.